# Optimal step size for gradient descent on quadratic function

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

First i have searched this forum but could not find a question that matched mine, though some are somewhat similar.

my issue is whether or not the signage matters when i try to calculate the optimum step size for the gradient descent method.

for gradient descent, the equation is given as, eqn 1,
$$x_{k+1} = x_{k} - \alpha\nabla f(x_{k})  $$
for gradient ascent, the equation is given as, eqn 2,
$$x_{k+1} = x_{k} + \alpha\nabla f(x_{k})$$

where $\alpha$ is the step size.

Using exact line search for a quadratic function, I get 2 different signages for the optimum step size depending on whether I use eqn 1 or eqn 2.

for a quadratic given by,
$$f(X)=\frac{1}{2} X^TQX+B^TX + C$$ and Q is positive definite.

Then I will end up with,
$$\alpha^*=-\frac{(\nabla f(x_{k}))^T\nabla f(x_{k})}{(\nabla f(x_{k}))^TQ\nabla f(x_{k})}$$
when using eqn1
and 
$$\alpha^*=\frac{(\nabla f(x_{k}))^T\nabla f(x_{k})}{(\nabla f(x_{k}))^TQ\nabla f(x_{k})}$$
when deriving using eqn 2.

MY QUESTION: Does the sign matter? Why do I end up with 2 different signs. Should I just take the absolute value for the step size. Then, if for example I am using gradient descent, I can susbsitute the absolute value for the optimum step size in to eqn 1, $x_{k+1} = x_{k} - \alpha\nabla f(x_{k})  $

pls help!!

Comment: In general I would use $$x_{k+1} = x_{k} + \alpha\nabla f(x_{k})$$ If it is an descent then $\nabla f(x_{k})$ will be negative. The formula is just a version of the linear approximation, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_approximation).

Comment: Thanks, i agree regarding taylor thoerem. However, lets say i evaluate $\nabla f(x_{k})$ as you suggest, this will point in the direction of the greatest increase of $f$ (i.e., ascent). For any choice of $\alpha$, I would assign a negative value to it. But if I want to find the optimum step length for a given step, for a quadratic, I would end up with an expression which is negative for $\alpha$. How can we explain that? Do we just ignore that negative sign and only care abouts its magnitude?

Comment: You´re welcome.

Comment: sorry, i didnt realise pushing enter would add the comment. i was hoping to add a new line. eek! im still confused. thanks for reading my post and commenting though, i appreciate it

Comment: For me is not clear how you´ve obtained $\alpha^*$. What is the underlying equation?

Comment: It can be obtained from page 7 of these lecture notes: http://www.princeton.edu/~amirali/Public/Teaching/ORF363_COS323/F14/ORF363_COS323_F14_Lec8.pdf

Comment: Also starting from, $(\nabla f(x_{k}))^T\nabla f(x_{k+1}) = 0$, for the case of a positive definite quadratic (as above), where $\nabla f = Qx + B$, then depending on whether we choose $x_{k+1} = x_{k} - \alpha\nabla f(x_{k})  $ or $x_{k+1} = x_{k} + \alpha\nabla f(x_{k})  $, will determine whether the $\alpha^*$ expression is positive or negative

Answer (score 1):

Say you are at iteration $k$ with $x_{k}$. Now, you define your descent step $x_{k+1} = x_{k} - \alpha\nabla f(x_{k}),$ with $\alpha > 0$ (otherwise, it would be an ascent step). Sub this in $f(X)=\frac{1}{2} X^TQX+B^TX + C$, you get a second order polynomial in $\alpha$, say $g(\alpha)$. As $Q$ is positive definite, the minimum for $g$ is reached at $g'(\alpha) = 0, $ which is, from your calculation, $$\alpha^*=\frac{(\nabla f(x_{k}))^T\nabla f(x_{k})}{(\nabla f(x_{k}))^TQ\nabla f(x_{k})}.$$ As expected $\alpha^*>0.$

Comment: Thanks, I understand the logic. Can you show your steps please?